# Spring Integration DAO best practices

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-integration, dao

Our RESTful WS designed without SI and have following DAO structure:

```
../dao/FooDao
../dao/BarDao
../dao/UserDao

../daoImpl/..
../service/..
```

But now we have found necessary to use above component.
I am a beginner in systems integration, and after reading "*Just Spring Integration*" I got basic knowledge about it.

**The question is:
what are best practices for creating channels, endpoints, etc. FOR DAO?**
*(It would be great if you provide links to articles, books, videos, etc., associated with SI and perhaps useful to me as a beginner.)*

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best resource on the matter for beginners is [Spring Integration in Action](http://www.manning.com/fisher/) book.

Any you DAO is just a POJO, hence any their methods can be exposed as `<service-activator>` reference to accept `request` message (just `payload` or together with `headers`) and produce some result which will be present as a `reply` message.

If you want to expose all those methods as Spring Integration Endpoints you don't have choice, unless provide separate `MessageChannel` and `<service-activator>` pair for each of them.

To be honest: Spring Integration isn't positioned as a DAO `facade`. It plays fully different, integration, role, when you need to ingest/emit the data from/to external systems using `Channel Adapters` (from big height, of course).

Spring Integration does not aim to be `development driven` framework, however it is possible. Thanks to `MessagingGateway`, SpEL and scripting support and that good hook to get deal with the POJO method invocation from many components.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
ie communication between DAO and customers through channel is unnecessary work?
_(I got advice about SI and DAO from my friend who works in a big company and where such practices are applicable. Although it seemed strange, I decided to find something in this direction.)_